# What is Fus Ro Dah?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I haven't yet played any Skyrim, but over and over I hear people saying they "fus ro dah"ed something or other.  It also seems to have become a meme of sorts.

What is Fus Ro Dah?  It sounds like it must be something that *pushes* given the way its used in sentences.  What does it mean in the context/story of the game?

If my car broke down, would I need to Fus Ro Dah it to a mechanic?

Comment: _It sounds like it must be something that pushes given the way its used in sentences._ Yup. In [Dragon Language](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Dragon_language) the three words mean "force", "balance", "push". Early on in the game you learn the shout "Fus!" but after exploring more and capturing dragon souls you complete it with Ro and Dah! (and learn a bunch of other shouts)

Comment: It also means "I want a divorce, and you get nothing!", if _you_ tell it to _your wife_.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Fus Ro Dah is the first shout in the game you learn: Unrelenting Force.

It sends enemies staggering back, and was first used in the Skyrim Trailer.

The trailer, however, doesn't do a very good job of capturing the feel of a "proper" Fus Ro Dah.

I direct you here:

So in conclusion - I would not FUS RO DAH my car to the mechanic, unless you wanted to buy a new car.

Comment: that second video is great. Real life force push =)

Comment: staggering back... more like staggering back or flying of mountains.

Answer (score 16):

In the game the player takes the role of a Dragonborn,  a mortal who born with the blood and soul of a dragon, who can learn a slain dragon's knowledge by absorbing it's soul. They can use Dragon Shouts (Thu'um) which are actually ancient and powerful words in Dragon Language. Each word has another effect and they can be empowered with combining them with other words. Unrelenting Force "*Fus Ro Dah*" is the first Dragon shout the player learns in the game. Fus means "Force". Ro means "Balance" and Dah means "Push". The effect of the shout varies, Fus will only stagger enemies in front of the player, "Fus Ro" will push back, "Fus Ro Dah" will send them in the air flying.

But it became very popular on the internet and people started making parody videos using the sound of "Fus Ro Dah" shout from the official gameplay trailer. It's like something both cool and funny at the same time. Like "*This is Sparta !*" from the 300.

Comment: So even partial shouts count, just for less?  That's interesting.

Comment: I guess so. Best call it a meme.